# Symfony / MVC write thin controllers

Tags: php, symfony, model-view-controller, controller

I've got a question regarding the construction of Symfony 2 controllers.
When i want to process a form, I create a seperate Form handler to process the form and call this handler within my controller:

```
public function registerAction()
{
  $formHandler = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form.handler');
  $confirmationEnabled = $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.registration.confirmation.enabled');
  $process = $formHandler->process($confirmationEnabled);
  return new JsonResponse($process);
}
```

Should I also use this approach of creating a Handler class for a Controller that just contains business logic and does not validate a form ?

e.g. my Controller action for registration confirmation would look like the following, when I outsource the logic in a seperate handler:

```
public function confirmAction($token)
{
    $formHandler = $this->container->get('acme.register_confirm.handler');
    $process = $formHandler->process($token);
    return new JsonResponse($process);
}
```

And I would handle the logic in the process method of this service.

OR should i let the logic in the controller and not create another seperate handler class ?

If i take this approach, almost all controllers would look the same:

1) Get the form handler
2) call the process method of the handler
3) return the response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second approach is better practice. Business logic should always be inside of [Services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html). This gives you a better [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and will make your code more reusable and testable. If you call your service `handler` or `MyFancyBusinessLogicService` is completely up to you.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. That means my Controller always just gets the request, calls the process method of my handler and returns the response. Checks like 'is_granted(ROLE_USER)' would also be placed in the handler / service? Or would I place such a check directly in the Controller?

Comment: Try to secure as much as possible over the [firewall](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/firewall.html). This way any insecure request will be caught even before the controller is called. If you need to check roles within your business logic make your service depend on the security component (for Symfony >2.6 the TokenStorage) to handle security there.